# Django ORM and templates, how do I view all of the variables available for a given QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I always have issues trying to figure out what the names of variables are available to use in a template. I'm wondering if there is something in the shell I can do to print out all objects available.

Let's say for example you have two models:

```
class Foo1(models.Model)
    id = models.Integer(primary_key=True)
    foo2 = models.ForeignKey(Foo2)

class Foo2(models.Model)
    id = models.Integer(primary_key=True)
    foo3 = models.Integer()
```

In the shell I do `p = Foo1.objects.all()` So now `p` is a QuerySet of all of the values that are contained in both `Foo1` and `Foo2` (because of the relationship).

Now in my template, in order to pull all of this data out I would normally do something like this:

```
{% for i in p %}
<p>{{ i.id }}</p>
<p>{{ i.foo2.id }}</p>
<p>{{ i.foo2.foo3 }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Right now I merely guess that the variable syntax to use is `i.id`, `i.foo2.id` and `i.foo2.foo3`, but for more complex QuerySet's this isn't always straightforward. Is there a way to output all of the available variables of a QuerySet and their names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
Foo.objects.values_list()
```

in the view and pass the object as a list rather than as a `queryset`.

Also check out:

```
Foo.objects.values()
```

Comment: `Foo.objects.values()` looks like it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to guess. You should be able to find out from the code of the models themselves.

If for some odd reason you haven't got access to the code - and I can't imagine why - you can always use the interactive shell - import your models there, do a query, then do `dir(my_obj)` to find a list of all the attributes of `my_obj`.